# How to automatically recover the data that has just been created?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-effect

I explain my problem:
I have two functions, one to create a garden and another a plot. So it's POST requests to my API but when I click submit, I have another function (which is a GET request) that retrieves the garden and the plots, this function works but I have to reload the page for them to appear: it's not added automatically. How can I do this?

I tried putting in the array of useEffect (which repeats my function to retrieve data from the Garden and the plots) the variable `garden` and `plot` or setGarden and `setPlot` but it doesn't work.

Here is the code of the GET Request :

```js
const [garden, setGarden] = useState([]);
const [plot, setPlot] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const gardenData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(user);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://127.0.0.1/api/garden?user=${parsedUserData.user.id}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token ${parsedUserData.token}`,
          },
        },
      );
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setGarden(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
        try {
          const plotResponse = await axios.get(
            `http://127.0.0.1/api/plots?garden=${response.data[0].id}`,
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Token ${parsedUserData.token}`,
              },
            },
          );
          if (plotResponse.status === 200) {
            setPlot(plotResponse.data);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Erreur ' + e);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    gardenData();
  }, []);
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the mentioned code is a part of an existing component with a return. It would be great to see where you run the POST method.

The `useEffect` hook gets triggered only on the mount of the component (as defined with the second argument - `[]`)

So you need to call the `gardenData` function after successfully performing the POST request. After that, the data will refresh and state will take care of the rest.